# jquery template showing Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-templates

Hi I am trying jquery template with ajax json, I am getting data from server but when i am passing that objects to template its showing Cannot read property 'push' of undefined error [Image screenshot of error][1]

I have gone through some research about this but am failing to get result. Request you all to please help me with same.

**Script template**

```
<ul class="entrylist" id="show_application_list">
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="show_application_list_template" >
 <li class="even">
 <div class="entry_wrap">
 <div class="entry_content2">
   <h4><a id='${jobid}' class='view_job_details'>${position}</a></h4>
   <big><strong>Applied On:</strong> ${applied_date}</big>
   <big><strong>Status:</strong> 

   {{if scheduled_date}}
   <button id="" class="stdbtn btn_lime show_application_details">Shortlisted</button>
   {{else}}
   <p><big><strong>Under Review</strong></big></p>
   {{/if}}
 </div>
 <br>
 <div class="entry_content2 show_application_details_content" style="display:none">

   <form class="stdform stdform2" method="post" action="#">
     <p>
       <label>Interview On</label>
       <span class="field">
       {{if scheduled_date}}
         ${scheduled_date}
       {{else}}
         <p><big><strong>Under Review</strong></big></p>
       {{/if}}
       </span>
     </p>

     {{if interview_response}}
       <p>
         <label>Interview Response</label>
         <span class="field">${interview_response}</span>
       </p>
       <p>
         <label>Interview Status</label>
         <span class="field">${interview_status}</span>
       </p>
       <p>
         <label>Interview Experience<small>Grade your experience out of 5 <small></label>
         <span class="field"><input type="number" min="0" max="5" name="lastname" id="lastname2" class="longinput"></span>
       </p>
       <p>
         <label>Comment</label>
         <span class="field"><textarea name="lastname" id="lastname2" class="longinput"></textarea></span>
       </p>
       <p class="stdformbutton">
         <button id="${interview_id}" type="button" class="stdbtn btn_lime update_interview_experience">Update Feedback</button>
       </p>
     {{/if}}

   </form>
 </div>
</div>
</li>
</script>               
</ul>
```

**Javascipt Code**

```
function show_application_employees(){
    $("#applicationlabel").hide();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:'functions/functions.php?activity=getapplicationemployees',
        success:function(data)
        {   

            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(obj)
            if(obj.length == 0){
                $("#applicationlabel").show();  
            }else{
                $("#applicationlabel").hide();
                $("#show_application_list").find(".even").remove();
                $("#show_application_list_template").tmpl(obj).appendTo("#show_application_list");
                $(".view_job_details").on("click",show_job_details);
                $(".show_application_details").on("click",show_application_details);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Some More scrren shots my code fails at this points: 
[error in jquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZOYo.png)

[error in jquery template js.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HftCz.png)

Comment: what console.log(obj) show ?

Comment: From your code I can only assume that you return an array of elements in your json and then you directly try to render it in your template whereas your template handles the rendering of individual elements inside the array. Either try to render one element from obj i.e. obj [0] or put a for each in your template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer, but debugging in the browser is as good as it gets. Below you can see the browser developer console. In the `Sources` tab:

1. Activate the `Pause on exceptions` button.
2. Rerun your page, and when you hit the exception where your error (`Cannot read property 'push'`) is thrown. Look at the Call Stack to find where your code fails.

Or put a breakpoint into the success function, and see how far you can step through your code.

The problem is definitely in your code, you need to pin-point it down a bit more. Post an update once you've found where exactly your code fails.

[image]